# "Превращение" sublime text 3 в Ide python?

Tags: python, sublime-text-3

В общем, гуглил, нашел пару плагинов: но увы, у меня просто напросто ничего не запускается(anaconda).
Разве что, при ctrl + b выводилось время выполнения и все, учитывая, что был вывод строки.
Пробовал sublimerepl - просто выбивает ошибку про filenotfound (вроде так)
Может, кто-то сталкивался ?
P.s: пробовал pycharm - не то, не могу после саблайма.
Спасибо(Питон 2)

Comment: Попробуйте pycharm ещё раз, хуже не будет.

Answer (score 1):

Нет, полноценного превращения в python ide из саблайма не получится. Вместо комбинаций клавиш в анаконде можно использовать контекстное меню (правой клавишей мыши), там добавляется пункт `anaconda` (я так и не выучил все эти сокращения). Он получше встроенного `goto`, но всё равно не дотягивает до полноценного ide.

Можно ещё полноценно настроить venv для каждого проекта, он получше начинает подсказывать импорты или автодополнять, но всё равно не дотягивает.

Единственное, чем можно скрасить себе пребывание на саблиме, это различные сниппеты или разметка синтаксиса. Например, вот набор [сниппетов для django](https://github.com/squ1b3r/Djaneiro).

Comment: Поставил себе anaconda — мало того что показывает подсказки в самые случайные моменты времени в ВНЕЗАПНО меняет поведение энтера, так ещё и содержимое этих подсказок за несколько секунд успевает аж четыре раза поменяться, хотя я ни клавиатуры, ни мыши вообще не касаюсь. Видимо, не судьба нам с топикстартером IDE и IDE-подобное юзать

Comment: Причём после написания этого комментария рандомные подсказки ВНЕЗАПНО пропали (из-за чего я коммент удалил), а после пяти минут работы столь же ВНЕЗАПНО вернулись. Вот зачем что-то подсказывать сразу после закрывающей скобки с вызовом функции, если это очевиднейший SyntaxError? ._.

Comment: @andreymal у меня оно иногда на другом рабочем столе всплывает на убунте при переключении из-за задержки. Очень "удобно". Частично отключается кстати через "enable_signatures_tooltio": false,

Answer (score 0):

Я обучаю детей. У многих компы слабые. Много чего пробовал тоже никак. Pycharm у них не идет норма. По этому с консоли просто запускаем. А так не давно встретил такую статью может получится попробуйте.

http://alexkorablev.ru/2015/12/07/python-ide/#.Wqk3iXXFL0o